# salesforce: how to retrieve the data in the fields that are selected by a view, using SOAP Enterprise with PHP

Tags: php, salesforce, enterprise

I have created a view in Salesforce which retrieves specified contacts and displays a limited number of fields. For example the view is called "Scotland managers" and only retrieves contacts where Location = "Scotland"

I am using the Salesforce enterprise force toolkit and PHP.

Essentially, does the view "Scotland Managers" in Salesforce use a select query?

If so, how can I get hold of that query and execute it using PHP api so I can import these contacts found by the view, into another MySQL database?